# Android Studio: "cannot resolve symbol" error in my R.java file

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

When I try to run my Android Studio project, the following error keeps popping up in my R.java file: "cannot resolve symbol 'speakers'"

Here's the specific code line that gave the error:

```
  public static final int fragment-speakers=0x7f0f00b3;
```

It only shows up with I try to run it, and no errors are shown when I sync the project.

Things I  have tried to resolve this issue:

- Clean Project
- Rebuild Project
- Invalidate Caches/Restart

The error still persists after trying those things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your Java syntax. You can not use '-' symbol in variable's name.

Try renaming fragment-speakers to fragment_speakers:

```
public static final int fragment_speakers = 0x7f0f00b3;
```

For proper variable naming convention and rules, check out https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html

Comment: I cannot believe that I missed that one. The fragment name was appropriate, but the id assigned used the wrong syntax.  Thank you.